# The permissions granted to user 'DomainName\UserName' are insufficient for performing this operation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I am using SSRS Reports in Asp.Net. I am using `ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials` and in this Credentials are system administrator username, password and domain. But I want to a simple user account who can view these reports by using an aspx page -> ReportViewer. In this aspx c# code page i want to pass simple user credential to `ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials` and this user is not administrator. But when i am using this it gives an error i.e.

```
The permissions granted to user 'DomainName\UserName' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)
```

How can we resolve this error?

How can we use simple user account instead of administrator account in `ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials`???

Answer (score 1):

You have to grant access to the report to the DomainName\UserName account in the report manager.